# Can't create polygon in an editable layer in ArcMap 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, layers, editing

There is an editable polygon layer in ArcGIS 10.3
I can edit already existing polygons but I can't create new ones. The layer does not appear in the "Create Features" list.

I have another polyline layer in the same dataframe that I can edit and create new features, so it's not a Problem of ArcGIS.

Is there a possibility to find out if my rights are somehow restricted (regarding this particular layer)? Do you have any other reasons in mind why I can't create features?

Comment: Sounds like a feature template issue - you either need to clear a definition query or update a feature template to allow you to create a feature that matches your definition query

Comment: Thanks for that quick response. How do I clear a definition query or update a feature template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't see feature templates for a particular layer, you can add them via the Create Features window:

Create Features window > Organize Templates > New Template > In the Create New Templates wizard, check the desired layers.

[image]

What also works (and that I use to do because it's straightforward), is: starting the Edit session by right-clicking the layer you want to edit (Edit Features > Start editing), instead of opening an edit session from the Editor toolbar. This adds the feature template automatically, if it's not there yet.

Comment: Okay, wow, that was easy solved. Thank you, it works!